# Trigger Custom Android Camera Online

Tags: javascript, android, ruby-on-rails, android-camera

I'm developing an app for an occasion, that would trigger the camera shutter to take a picture and save it to the SD Card.

The trigger will be fired by the user, who's standing in front of the camera. What's probably the best way to implement the trigger part of the app?

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use timers or or a handler with postdelayed.

Comment: Can I do this with a click of a button from a website?